# Sum up column values in DataTable based on the value of another column

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a DataTable, like this:

```
Amount | Count
-----------------------
20.0   | 2
42.0   | 1
78.0   | 5
91.0   | 2
```

I'd like to sum up the `Count` column, based on what's in the `Amount` column.

I want to find the sum of `Count` for all `Amount` between 0 - 50 and 51-100, which would be 3 and 7 in this example.

Is there a way to quickly get that data?

Here's what I have currently:

```
foreach (int min in ranges)
{
    int max = min + 50;
    int count = 0;

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt)
    {
        if (dr["Amount"] > min && dr["Amount"] < max)
            count += dr["Count"];
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a more elegant solution

Comment: What solutions have you tried so far?  It seem straightforward enough.  You find all rows with an amount in the given range and sum their counts.  Do that for all ranges.

Comment: @Servy - I've tried looping through each row, checking the `Amount` field, storing the `Count` value in a temporary field, etc. But that's kinda messy. I didn't know if there was a quick way to do this using LINQ or something.

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and describe what problems that solution has.

Comment: Give LINQ to DataTable a try - the shortest and most elegant solution

Comment: @Servy - edited my original post. It technically works, I'm just looking for a more elegant solution, and one that could possibly improve the performance.

Comment: Seems fine to me.  It's fairly short, works just fine, is clear to the reader, etc.  Just use that.  If you would prefer a LINQ based solution, have you attempted a LINQ based solution?  Have you been able to write a part of the query, have you looked into what operators you're likely going to need to use?

Comment: @Servy - I haven't attempted a LINQ based solution because I'm not that familiar with LINQ, that's why I'm here. I don't know if I should use LINQ aggregators or a simple LINQ query. I imagine I will need to use `Sum` combined with a `Between` statement

Comment: @Steven "I haven't attempted a LINQ based solution" that's a problem.  Make an attempt yourself.  See how far you can get.  If you don't try, you don't know that you can't do it.  There really are not that many LINQ operators, you can likely look through what's there to get a feel for which are likely to be useful to you.  There is indeed a `Sum` operator, so keep that in mind.  There is no `Between` operator, but there is an operator that you can use to filter a collection to just those items that meet come condition, such as those who's value is between two numbers.

Comment: @Servy

"There is no Between operator, but there is an operator that you can use to filter a collection to just those items that meet come condition, such as those who's value is between two numbers"

...and that would be?

I understand wanting to encourage people who come here to try and come up with a solution on their own, but I feel like you're being purposeful unhelpful at this point.

I have no experience with LINQ, so I tried searching for a solution and came up with nothing. I researched LINQ in general a little bit, and came up with nothing to help me. I'm stuck. That's why I'm here.

Comment: Just giving you a solution that you wouldn't understand or be able to replicate would be unhelpful.  Teaching you how to solve these types of problems yourself is quite useful, in my mind.  But if you don't want my help that's fine.

Comment: I'd love your help - you just aren't providing me any. You don't have to give me code that I can copy and paste, but a push in the right direction would be nice.

@YuriyGalanter recommended LINQ to DataTable, which I'm taking a look at now. That was very helpful of him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good link for learning Linq is [101 Linq samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b). The following piece of code should give you a good starting point though it creates ranges from 0 to <50, 50 to <100 and so on. It assumes that the ranges do have regular intervals.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));
dt.Rows.Add(20, 2);
dt.Rows.Add(42, 1);
dt.Rows.Add(78, 5);
dt.Rows.Add(91, 2);
var result = from DataRow x in dt.Rows
                group x by ((int)x["Amount"]) / 50 into grp 
                select new {LowerBoundIncl = grp.Key * 50, 
                        UpperBoundExcl = (grp.Key + 1) * 50, 
                        TotalCount = grp.Sum(y => (int) y["Count"])};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess the OP would have to try hard before solving his **actual and specific** problem from this answer.